# explode function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to programming , i have a problem while using explode function ie, after i explode the value and pass those value to a model to retrive records from db only the last value from the exploded data is showing.
ex i have impoded data as (test,test1,test2) after explode the data is like(testtest1test2) here i pass these value to model to take records from a table where a field name is equal to the exploded value.I dont't know how to explain this properly please forgive me.

```
public function location($id) {
    $query = $this->gt_pav_model->select($id);
    $data['selectdata'] = $query->result();

    foreach( $data['selectdata'] as $s) {
        $explode = $s->package_id; // this is to get imploded data from db
    }

    $t = explode(",", $explode); 

    foreach( $t as $tt) {
        $query = $this->gt_pav_model->select_pa($tt);
        $data['dataa'] = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('pav/pavdetails',$data);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Sooraj S  still facing issue? after using my answer code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function location($id) {
$final_result = array();
$result= $this->gt_pav_model->select($id)->result();
foreach( $result as $key=> $re) {
      $explode               = $re->package_id;
      $t                     = explode(",", $explode);
      $param                 = $t[1]; 
      $datas = $this->gt_pav_model->select_pa($param)->result(); 
      $final_result[$key] => $datas;
  }    
  $this->load->view('pav/pavdetails',array('datas'=>$final_result));
}
```

You can print result in your view page `<?php print_r($datas); ?>`